# Selenium stand alone server is not able to launch a local Firefox driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i am using selenium stand alone server 2.3.0.jar for my project.It's working fine in IE,Safari,but i am not able to get same response(not able to launch browser window in firefox,chrome.
For chrome after i have given webdriver.chrome.driver it's just opening blank window,not taking url.

Please help me..

Comment: More information is needed. What version of Selenium? 2.3.0? That's months old. Update. What version of Chrome? What version of ChromeDriver? What version of Firefox? What version of Windows? What version of IE? What version of the IEDriver? What version of Safari?

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing is a problem that occurs when you are trying to run an older version of Selenium when the newer version of the Chrome driver (or IE driver) has been updated beyond the supported version at the time that the Selenium .jar was generated.   Unfortunately, the error you get in this situation is **nothing** and/or a hung browser.  You would get a similar error if a firewall was blocking your JSON packets from getting to the port of the driver server.

In order to get proper behavior, as-of November 12, 2013, make sure you have upgraded Selenium to the latest **2.37.0** and also update to the Chrome **2.6** and IE driver **2.37.0** .dlls .  This is important because modern browsers like Firefox, Chrome, and now IE11 will auto-update to the point where you need to increment your Selenium version to keep up.